# Setting minimum height of the UICollectionView without subclassing UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I want to set a minimum height for my collection view.

Is there any way to do this without subclassing UICollectionViewFlowLayout?

Comment: Minimum height of what? Frame? Content size?

Comment: Content size. I want my footer stays in the bottom of the screen if there is not enough content.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that without subclassing UICollectionViewFlowLayout. Why don't you want to do that? It should be really easy, you'd only have to override one method "collectionViewContentSize".